# How do I remove the duplicate for rounded corder

Tags: html, css

This code is

```
   -moz-border-radius-topleft: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px 3px 0px 0px;
   border-radius: 3px 3px 0px 0px;
```

is making rounded corner.

I have a class roundcorder with the above 4 rows. This class roundcorder is used in the two selectors section and footer.

As it is now I have added the four rows that make the rounded corner to this selector

```
    nav li a:link, 
    nav li a:visited
```

This will cause duplicate of code which I don't want. So my question is how can I just use the class roundcorder from selector

```
nav li a:link, 
nav li a:visited
```

Here is the complete markup and css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset = "utf-8">
      <title>Inlämningsuppgift 1</title>
      <style type = "text/css">
         body
         {
            font-size:small;
            width:72em;
            text-align:center;
            background : #87a5be url(bg.jpg) no-repeat right bottom fixed;
            background-repeat:no-repeat;
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            margin:0.2em auto;
         }

        .roundcorder
        {
           -moz-border-radius-topleft: 3px;
          -moz-border-radius-topright: 3px;
          -webkit-border-radius: 3px 3px 0px 0px;
           border-radius: 3px 3px 0px 0px;
        }

        header img
        {
           float:left;
        }

        header time
        {
           font-size:120%;
           float:right; 
           font-weight:bold;
        }

        header div:after, 
        nav:after
        {
           content :".";
           display:block;
           height:0;
           clear:both;
           visibility:hidden;
        }

        nav
        {
           margin-top:1em;
           font-weight:bold;
           color:#fff; 
        }

        nav ul
        {
           list-style:none;
           margin:0;
           padding:0;
        }

        nav li
        {
           float: left;
           min-width : 8em;
           text-align : center;   
           margin-right:0.5em; 
       }

       nav li a:link, 
       nav li a:visited
       {
           background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
           color: rgb(0,0,0);
           text-decoration: none;
           display: block;
           padding: 0.75em;
           -moz-border-radius-topleft: 3px;
           -moz-border-radius-topright: 3px;
           -webkit-border-radius: 3px 3px 0px 0px;
           border-radius: 3px 3px 0px 0px;
        }   

        #info nav li.info a:link, 
        #info nav li.info a:visited
        {
           background-color: #fff;
        }

        nav li a:hover 
        {
           background-color:grey;  
        }

        .content 
        {
           background-color: #fff;
           color: #000;
           padding: 0.2em;
        }

        .content h1
        {
           font-size:200%;
        }

        .content p
        {
           text-align:left;
           font-size:110; 
           padding:0.5em;
        }

        footer
        {
           background:#e3e3e3;
        }

        footer p
        {
           text-align:left;
        }
      </style>
   </head>

   <body id="info">
      <header>
         <div>
            <img src="logo.jpg" alt="Euro travel logo"  />
            <time>2013-09-05 16:00</time>
         </div>

         <nav>
            <ul>
               <li class="info"><a href="#">Information</a></li>
               <li class="tidtabell"><a href="#">Tidtabell</a></li>
               <li class="bokning"><a href="#">Bokning</a></li>
               <li class="kontakt"><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
            </ul>
         </nav>
      </header>

      <section class="content roundcorder">
         <h1>Välkommen till flygbolagets Euro Travel hemsida</h1>
         <p> Här kommer jag senare att fylla på med mer information.</p>
      </section>

      <footer class="roundcorder">
         <h4>&copy copyright</h4>
         <p>Flygbolaget Euro Travel är ganska nytt med sitt huvudkontor i Stockolm. 
            Euro Travel har som målsättning att bli värdsledande inom 3 år.</p> 
         <p> De har nyligen infört ett poängsystem
           som innebär att ju mer du flyger dessto fler poäng får du som du kan använda 
           vid  nästa flygbiljett.
          Dessutom ehålls alltid 20% rabatt om du köper en biljett 3månader före avresan.
         </p>

         <address>Adress: Euro Travel 
           <br />Kundservice Kungsgatan 123 45 Stockhom
           Email:EuroTravel@travel.se <br />
           Tel:08-57 27 489<br />
           www.eurotravel.se
         </address>
      </footer>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: BTW, you can replace your two `-moz-` border radius properties with one:  `-moz-border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;` (and you do not need to write `px` when the value is `0`.)

Answer (score 2):

Just add the class to the link:

```
<li class="info roundcorder"><a href="#">Information</a></li>
```

But, I would write just `border-radius`, without vendor prefixes; http://caniuse.com/border-radius

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using dynamic stylesheet languages such as [LESS](http://lesscss.org/), this is the only way:

```
.roundcorder,
nav li a:link, 
nav li a:visited
{
   -moz-border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
   -webkit-border-radius: 3px 3px 0px 0px;
   border-radius: 3px 3px 0px 0px;
}

nav li a:link, 
nav li a:visited
{ 
   background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
   color: rgb(0,0,0);
   text-decoration: none;
   display: block;
   padding: 0.75em;
}
```

- P.S - Notice the two `-moz` lines where united into one like @Sparky has suggested. I personally think it's advisable to stop using this prefix at all, for it's already unnecessary on the last 20 versions of FF or so.

Comment: Perhaps you can mention how the OP can write his two `-moz-` border radius properties with one line.

Comment: No it doesn't work when I change from this
nav li a:link, 
nav li a:visited
to this .roundcorder,
nav li a:link, 
nav li a:visited now the rounder corner does not work

Comment: @user2658578 You did what? I can't understand. Post your relevant code to http://jsfiddle.net so we can take a look